# Scala Play Framework 2.1.1 JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Can someone explain this syntax that's from [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonRequests)?

```
implicit val rds = (
  (__ \ 'name).read[String] and
  (__ \ 'age).read[Long]
  ) tupled
```

I especially don't understand where `__`, `\`, and `tupled` expressions are coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`__` is an alias for JsPath companion object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.package)

`\` is the operator to parse the [`symbol`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Symbol) to read from the Json object.

And `tupled` just puts them into a [`tuple`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2) so you can do something like `case (name, age) =>` as in the example in the doc you posted.

Comment: What about the single quotation mark in front of the field name?

Comment: @Caskman That is a [scala symbol](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Symbol). Think of it as more of a basic ID than a string would be.

Comment: @Caskman Did I help you out or do you still have more questions?

Comment: Sorry I got sidetracked, that helps a lot, thank you very much!